# Wordpress ACF selection: Only first object returned when dynamically using categories as choices

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to modify an ACF selection field by dynamically fetching Post categories, so that user can select between different (It's for a Blog page template). I'm using the function according to ACF, right now, only the first category is returned.

This is what I've got in `functions.php`:

function acf_load_color_field_choices( $field ) {

```
function categoryName() {
        $args = array(
            'type'       => 'post',
            'taxonomy'   => 'category',
            'parent'     => 0, // get top level categories
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'hierarchical'  => 1,
            'pad_counts'    => 0
        );

        $categories = get_categories( $args );

        foreach ( $categories as $category ){

            echo $category->name;

        }
    }


    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();


    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = categoryName();


    // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
    $choices = explode("\n", $choices);


    // remove any unwanted white space
    $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);


    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {

        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {

            $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;

        }

    }


    // return the field
    return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=blog_by_cat', 'acf_load_color_field_choices');
```

I've also tried:

```
function acf_load_cat_field_choices( $field ) {


    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting

    $choices = get_categories();
    $value = get_categories();

    // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
    $choices = explode("\n", $choices);

    // remove any unwanted white space
    $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);

        // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {

        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {

            $field['choices'][ $value->slug ] = $choice->name;


        }

    }

    // return the field
    return $field;
```

This returns nothing

And:

```
function acf_load_cat_field_choices( $field ) {


    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting

    $choices = get_categories();

    // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
    $choices = explode("\n", $choices);

    // remove any unwanted white space
    $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);

        // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) ) {

        foreach( $choices as $choice ) {

            $field['choices'][$choice] = $choice;


        }

    }

    // return the field
    return $field;

}
```

This returns "Array" (one time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do this correctly:

function acf_load_cat_field_choices( $field ) {

```
// reset choices
$field['choices'] = array();

// get the textarea value from options page without any formatting

$getCatSlugs = array('all_posts');
$getCatNames = array('All Posts');


$args = array(
        'type'          => 'post',
        'taxonomy'      => 'category',
        'parent'        => 0, // get top level categories
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical'  => 1,
        'pad_counts'    => 0
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ){

        $getCatSlugs[] = $category->slug;
        $getCatNames[] = $category->name;


}

$values = implode("\n", $getCatSlugs);
$labels = implode("\n", $getCatNames);


$values = explode("\n", $values);
$labels = explode("\n", $labels);



// loop through array and add to field 'choices'


    foreach( array_combine($values, $labels ) as $value => $label ) {
        $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;       
   }


// return the field
return $field;
```

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=post_by_cat', 'acf_load_cat_field_choices');

Answer (score 0):

`categoryName()` is not returning anything. Instead of echoing `$category->name`, you should pack them into an array, and return that array?